# List of files where the line count is greater than 2

Tags: command

Bunch of files exist in a directory. Some files have 1 line in it, some files have more number of lines.

I'm trying to display filenames from a particular directory(with full path),  where the linecount in the file is > 2.

I am up to here, to display files in a directory.
find /abc/def -maxdepth 1 -type f

Comment: It's not clear in your question whether you want files with 2 lines or more or lines with 3 lines or more (more than 2 lines).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
    -exec sh -c 'test $( wc -l {} | cut -f1 -d" " ) -gt "2"' \; -print
```

**you have to be careful if some alien file called `$(rm -rf ~)` is found in your directory, this may cause the command to delete all of your data in that directory**

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` search for files in the current directory for depth 1 which means don't descend into subdirectories

`-exec sh -c`  execute a command where here I'm running a script for one command

`'test $( wc -l {} | cut -f1 -d" " ) -gt "2"'` this is the command which is counting number of lines of each file greater than 2.

Then print the output

Comment: That command deleted all my data (there was a file called `$(rm -rf ~)` in the current directory.

Comment: That's a special case which is not indicated by the OP, so you can't punish me for something not listed in the question, So it's not fair to downvote

Comment: This is working. If possible, could you please explain the command in detail.

Comment: ok Im going to do that, but please note to mark as answer

Comment: Up/down votes are not to punish people but to help determine what is a good answer or not. Embedding arbitrary data in shell code is the worst kind of bad practise you can come up with in shell scripting.

Comment: Just to complement my initial comment: this solution will fail if the file names contain any shell special character (with possible dramatic effect). that includes blanks, newlines, `|<>#~()*&$"[{'`  and more depending on the shell implementation. That's also very inefficient in that it runs several commands per file and reads the files fully.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `awk` or `mawk` [and a few others](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607), to list regular files in the current directory that contain at least 3 lines:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -size +2c -exec awk '
   FNR==3{print FILENAME; nextfile}' {} +
```

(note that that counts non-terminated lines as well. If a file contains `a\nb\nc` instead of `a\nb\nc\n`, that still considers that file has 3 lines even if `wc -l` would only return 2. `-size +2c` is just an optimisation to skip opening and reading files that have fewer than 3 bytes, since those can't contain 3 lines).

That's efficient in that it runs as few commands as possible, and stops processing a file as soon as it sees the 3rd line as opposed to reading the file fully to find the number of lines.

If your shell is `zsh`, you can shorten it to

```
awk 'FNR==3{print FILENAME; nextfile}' ./*(D.L+2)
```

`find . ! -name . -prune` is the standard equivalent of GNU's `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` (*prune* every directory but `.`).

(note that the `awk` code above will also work in `awk` implementations that don't support `nextfile`, it's just that it will read the files fully there, that `nextfile` statement will just be treated as a variable reference).

Comment: If number of lines must be *greater* than 2, then should be `FNR==3` inside `awk` and `\n.*\n` (or similar) as a `pcregrep` pattern.

Comment: @jimmij, yes, though the wording of OP's question suggests he wants files with at least 2 lines as opposed to a number of lines _strictly_ greater than 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Hsc . -- * | sed -n '/:[0-2]$/!s/:.*$//p'
```

but do not take empty lines into count. If you'd like take it into counting:

```
grep -Hsc '$' -- * | sed '/:[0-2]$/d;s/:.*$//'
```

Comment: Comment from @Stéphane Chazelas about `*` expanding to something starting with `-` in 3..., 2... ;)

Comment: Also note that `.` matches valid characters only (why not simply `grep '^'`). It searches in non-regular files, it assumes file names don't contain colons or newline characters. -H is a GNU extension.

Comment: Note that using `./*` as opposed to `-- *` is safer as `-- *` still fails for a file called `-`.

Comment: Also note that it ignored hidden files (contrary to the OP's find approach).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If you'd like to include hidden files it easy can be done by adding to script `.*` : `grep -sc '$' -- * .* | ...`

Comment: Also note that it reads the files fully even though you know you've got at least 3 lines as soon as you've read one byte past the 2nd newline character.